# Why is pandas.date_range() so slow to generate months?

Tags: pandas

Simple observation:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('''pd.date_range("1900-01-01", "2017-07-02", freq='H')''', 'import pandas as pd', number=1000)
3.4257616080285516
>>> timeit.timeit('''pd.date_range("1900-01-01", "2017-07-02", freq='MS')''', 'import pandas as pd', number=1000)
62.60253554501105
>>> timeit.timeit('''pd.date_range("1900-01-01", "2017-07-02", freq='D')''', 'import pandas as pd', number=1000)
0.24156528399907984
>>> timeit.timeit('''pd.date_range("1900-01-01", "2017-07-02", freq='M')''', 'import pandas as pd', number=1000)
67.81731529999524
```

Why is it so slow to generate months (M) or month starts (MS)? There's about 1400 months in the specified range, and it takes ~60 milliseconds on my machine to generate them. On the other hand it takes 250 times less to generate days (about 43k) in the same range.

I need month starts and this is too slow for me. Can my code be optimized?

Benchmarks run on macOS x86-64 with Pandas 0.23.1 and getting similar results on Linux x86-64.

Comment: I can confirm the timeit results on macOs High Sierra: about 73.6 ms for months and 269 µs for days, with pandas 0.22.0. Screenshot [here](https://imgur.com/a/OZotuYg).

Comment: I've been pointed out that this is a known issue in Pandas https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16463#issuecomment-303529081